# Recommendations for zoom lenses for an iPhone 3GS

Tags: zoom, iphone

I enjoy taking pictures for fun with my iPhone 3GS, but I've now reached a point where I would like to be able to zoom in a bit on my motives, and I don't like the digital zoom.

Now I've seen that it is possible to buy small zoom lenses (so I can have them in my pocket all the time) that can be attached to the iPhone - http://photojojo.com/store/awesomeness/iphone-telephoto-lens/ - but before buying I would like to hear if anyone in here have experiences to share, and perhaps even recommend this or another product.

Should I buy this item?

---

2017 update:  Now a few years later, I agree with everybody who said this was a bad idea.  I got a iPhone 4S and bought an olloclip which was nice for macro pictures etc but cumbersome to use.  So the long term solution was to get a better camera.  I now have a Canon 70D I use primarily and a Sony RX100M4 for having in my pocket.  And I still use my Phone a lot but just for taking quick shots.

Comment: @Jerry The sample pictures (available through the OP's link) are telling: even at 2 x 3" on the screen, they are strongly blurred.  Sounds like a good outfit for capturing pictures of UFOs :-).

Comment: @whuber: I suppose in fairness, you shouldn't expect *too* much from an 8x zoom that costs only $35, especially when it's an add-on, not a complete lens on its own.

Comment: I ended up loosing my 3GS, bought a 4S and the original Olloclip (http://www.olloclip.com/product/).  Did not get me zoom, but macro which was much more fun :)

Comment: Please don't edit the solution / resolution into the question. Instead, please write that information into an answer. That way, you can mark the answer as accepted, since it's the answer that most helped, resolved, or applied to the problem of the question. Questions, answers, and marking as accepted is how Stack Exchange is supposed to work.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have the lens, but as some comments above say - their sample images are quite telling.

1. Their very best pictures they chose to share as sample images are quite blurry and on a real camera would probably be tossed as unusable.  (As best you can tell from their image sizes).
2. They show using a tripod and thats going to be needed in the majority of cases.  You'll probably not have a high shutter speed, an iPhone isn't built for steady holding, and you're lacking any real image stabilization.

Unless you're taking *really* well lit pictures constantly (in order to get the shutter speed high), skip it and get a pocket-able real P&S camera or live with the existing iPhone limitations.

Answer (score 4):

Part of learning about photography is learning to recognize and exploit the strengths and weaknesses of different cameras. The iPhone camera is very good for a phone, but **telephoto shots are not its strength**, and never will be. No accessory is going to change that.

I have three specific recommendations for you.

1. Use shoe-leather zoom: move closer to your subject.
2. Learn to love landscape shots. I have [taken several](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ieure/4764846341/lightbox/) [very nice](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ieure/5080357374/lightbox/) [wide shots](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ieure/4838178633/lightbox/) with my iPhones (both 3GS and 4). During the iPhone 4 keynote, lots of the shots they used were wide, such as the Golden Gate Bridge; these are the kinds of shots it is very good at. I don’t know if I’ve *ever* shot a really excellent portrait with one. You might also want to look at [The Best Camera Is The One That’s With You](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321684788), a book of iPhone photos, to get a better idea of what your camera is capable of.
3. If you really cannot live without a zoom lens, buy yourself a dedicated camera. Either a nice compact (The Canon PowerShot S90/S95 are amazing; I *love* mine) or a superzoom. You’d have to tote around a special case lens with the PhotoJojo setup, so carrying a separate camera wouldn’t be all that much worse. [SnapSort](http://snapsort.com) is a fantastic site for comparing cameras.

Answer (score 0):

Here's maybe a slightly different viewpoint to the general consensus opinion of 'this is a bad idea':

Will adding a lens modifier- generally speaking a modifier of significantly lower quality than the lens itself- detract from the quality of a lenses optics? Yes. Absolutely. Your picture will never be as sharp or accurate as if you hadn't added the modifier to the front of the lens. In fact, it will be significantly degraded. Period.

Should you buy this item? That depends on what you're looking to accomplish with your photography, and what (in general) you want your pictures to look like. If you like the 'lo-fi' photography look that can be achieved through the use of things like Lensbabys, and Lomo cameras, then you're likely to think the look that comes from one of these modifiers is cool! If, on the other hand, you're hoping for performance that in any way rivals an actual dedicated zoom lens on a 'real' camera, it would be better to avoid such modifiers because the quality of the images you'll be able to make won't even be in the same city as a dedicated lens would, let alone the same ballpark.

Personally, I think this modifier looks like a heck of a lot of fun for use as a 'goof around' camera attachment, and at ~$35 it's a small enough investment that it seems like a bit of  'no-brainer' to give it a go...

Comment: I'm not into professional photography at all.  It is just for fun and learning :)

Comment: Then I'll bet that the attachment will be a lot of fun for you to use! Like I said, I think it's a bit of a 'no brainer' to spend ~$35 on something like this...